# How to dim other div on clicking input box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, effect

I am having 3 input box, and i would like to dim the complete screen except the particular input box which is being clicked.
I tried this: 
http://jsbin.com/equre3/2

But when i click the textbox everything including the text box get dimmed.

On text box click this is what i needed.

```
all div: opacity: .5  
contactForm div: opacity .75  
current labelTextHolder div: opacity: 1
```

Also, what changes should i do in CSS so that text and input show in one row.

Comment: please make note, if you apply styling(opacity) to an Element, opacity also applies to the child Elements

Comment: @Avinash: when i will change the opacity of parent it will obviously change the opacity of child, but after that when i am changing opacity of child it should override the existing opacity of child. isn' it ?

Comment: well, you maybe  right :) what about the remaining `div` elements in your page ??. you're setting every `div` element's opacity to **0.5** and you're just changing the opacity of `.labelTextHolder` what about remaining `div`(**parents**) ?

Comment: actually I don't think it works that way. Opacity cascades whether you like it to or not. The child uses the parents final opacity as it's base. So if you set the parent to 0.5 and the child to 0.5, the child will look like 0.25

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, this is just a barebones example...I'm not going to animate it or add any labels or inputs or anything...but here's how it works in principle.  The most important thing to remember about manipulating the CSS `z-index` property is that any element with a z-index MUST be positioned (i.e. `position:relative`, `position:absolute`, etc.):

HTML (hypothetically):

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="div1" class="usable"></div>
<div id="div2" class="usable"></div>
<div id="div3" class="usable"></div>​
```

CSS:

```
​#overlay {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:0;
}

div.usable {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F0F;
}

div.active {
    background-color:#F00;
    z-index:5;
}
```

jQuery:

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.usable").hover(
    function(e){
        $("#overlay").css({"z-index":2,"opacity":.5});
       $(this).addClass("active"); 
    },
    function(e){
        $("#overlay").css({"z-index":0,"opacity":0});
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
  );
});​
```

As for the whole "text and input in one row" thing, I'd recommend looking at changing the `display` CSS properties of the inputs and labels to show them inline or inline-block if that's feasible within your application.  Example:

```
input.rowStyle {display:inline;}
```

Hope this helps!

​

Comment: doesn't really work, the overlay covers the entire page, here's how it actually works: https://jsfiddle.net/a8454az7/

Answer (score 2):

When you change opacity of an element, all children get the same opacity.

Two options :

1- if your targeted browsers support it, use rgba for background of your container.

2- use absolute positioning to rearrange your elements so that your content is not a child of your container, but is positioned above it.